# Follow feature extension

Tags: yii, yii-extensions

Is there a yii extension (or anything similar) that allows "following" feature like the one on yiiframework website ?

It was mentioned here:
[linky](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/15072-following-an-extension-or-wiki-article/page__p__75026__hl__follow#entry75026)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not know about any extension for this case. But it is easily implementable. I can give you an idea to implement this feature.

First create a table which holds the following column:
for example(**tbl_followers**)

- id
- User ID
- Page ID (It can be different, You may have an extension page so page ID will be your extension page id)
- date (or any additional columns)

Now, You can hold all users who want to follow your page. This is possible to insert into into mentioned table by clicking on *follow link* for example.

Probably, You might have an action for sending post to your page(for instance: **actionCreatePost**). By using Yii's event, create an event **onCreatePost()** and in this method select all all subscribed users from your table (tbl_followers) and send an email to user's email address.

This is completely an idea. You can do different :)